# Transit through Hong Kong to Singapore from canada

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, hong-kong, canadian-citizens

I hold a Canadian passport and flying Air canada  to Hong Kong and 4 hours later fly Air Singapore to Singapore where we join a cruise. Do I need a visa for Hong Kong

Answer (score 1):

When in airport transit in Hong Kong, their entry requirements don't apply, besides the fact that you can enter the country and stay for up to 90 days.

So no, only your passport is needed.